# Remove System Account and User Groups from people search results in O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, search-results, people-search

I am working on `O365` and have a requirement where I only need to display `Users` in my people search results. Currently the result also displays few service accounts which I do not want.

Is there a way to remove the `user groups`, `service accounts` and `non people users` from results?

If yes, then please provide the approach.

Comment: Which user groups do you want to exclude?

Comment: All the non users and groups.

Comment: Please be more specific. In my case I see service accounts but I don't understand what Groups you are referring to or where they are located. I can't help if you are not more specific.

Comment: Groups meaning - Product Owners , Product Viewers etc. I hope you are clear now.

Comment: Nope...how are groups showing up in your People Search Results? Do you have a screen shot? I have never seen groups in the results.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott In my search results I see the service accounts only. How do we eliminate them from results.

Comment: Are you importing User Profiles? You should see more than just the service accounts. The best way to remove the service accounts is to not import them.

Comment: Sorry, Just noticed that you said O365. Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be possile using SharePoint Result Sources using a Search Query that excludes Active Directory User Groups or any other object located in a certain Organization Unit (OU)

- [Configure result sources for search in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [Query variables in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx)

Comment: Do you think this will be applicable and work in Office 365?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the accounts. In my case they all start with "_spo". Open your search center and edit the People Search results web part. Add an exclusion to the query like `-accountname:_spo*`. in my environment that excludes them. Another alternative is to copy the existing People Result Source and edit your copy adding the above exclusion. Then change the Result Source that the web part uses.

In this same way you should be able to exclude external (or guest) accounts with a query exclusion like: `-accountname:EXT` (or in our case we tag all external users as "(EXTERNAL)" so our exclusion is `-PreferredName:" (EXTERNAL)"`)

Bottom line, create a query that only selects the accounts you wish to exclude and then negate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set “ShowInAddressList” Azure AD User object property to false for accounts you do not want to see in Microsoft 365 Search.

“ShowInAddressList” Azure AD User object property is editable and synchronized to “SPS-HideFromAddressLists” SharePoint User Profile property (takes minutes)

“Show in Global Address List” under m365 Admin Center and “Hide from global address list (GAL)” under Exchange Admin Center respect “ShowInAddressList” Azure AD User object property change (but not vise versa).

[Hide User Accounts from Microsoft 365 People Search](https://vladilen.com/sharepoint/hide-non-personal-account-from-microsoft-365-search/)